# How to set activated link color in angular 6

Tags: angular-ui-router, angular5, angular6

I am trying to set activated link color should be red uisng primeng angular 6.How can i do it this.

```
    ngOnInit() {
    this.items = [
        {label:'Home', routerLink:'/home'},
        {label:'Cycle', routerLink:'/cycle'},
        {label:'Football', routerLink:'/football'},
        {label:'Cat', routerLink:'/cat'} 
    ];
    }
```

Comment: routerLinkActive="className"

Comment: Ya..that is working..But i want active previous links of activated link and after activated link next links unactevate..How we can do it?